# CodeIgniter 4 Structure & Routes

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-4

I'm using CodeIgniter 4 and I've set up a Modules directory in my App directory structure. I've setup my route, controller, and view properly so everything is working. However In my echo view() I have the whole path written out. I was wondering what can I do to simply call the views within the folder structure like header, home, and footer.

My Structure:

[image]

`App/Config/Routes.php`

```
$routes->get('users', '\App\Modules\Users\Controllers\Users::index');
```

`App/Modules/Users/Controllers/Users.php`

```
namespace App\Modules\Users\Controllers;

namespace App\Modules\Users\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use \App\Modules\Users\Views;

class Users extends BaseController
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function index()
    {
        echo view('\App\Modules\Users\Views\header');
        echo view('\App\Modules\Users\Views\home');
        echo view('\App\Modules\Users\Views\footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a structural issue in your project. Lets say the Admin module, it should be at the level of the app rather than nested within the app, this will help with autoloading the modules and make it easier for developer, in your current structure it is adding extra complexities.

Comment: Thank you, and I did make the change it was much easier and loaded so much faster.

To answer my own question, the way I have it written is how it should function based on my file structure and CI4. I'm used to CI3 so my perception was slightly off.

Here is the article that I found that explained it to me in layman's terms: https://timbrownlaw.com/blog/codeigniter-4-hmvc-just-like-in-codeigniter-3-but-simpler/

Comment: This is a good article for reference. However, I went with the approach one where I kept every module outside app. This made it easy for me to modularize the code and manage it.

Comment: I'm using your recommended approach. It's actually working out very well. Thank you!